# Secure Channel Protocol 01 and 03 in Win32API DLL

Tags: c++, smartcard, apdu, winscard

I need to make Extended Auth(APDU:8482000010...) with Secure Channel Protocol version 01 and 03, in order to update IC Card data.

Really stuck on how to demonstrate this in Win32API DLL(Microsoft Visual Studio as IDE and compiler) using winscard.

Can you guys help me if have information/knowledge and examples?

To be clear, steps are:

1. Select Applet (00A40400...). It is done.
2. Prepare Update (80500000... and 00C00000...). Also ok.
3. Ext Auth with SCP(#01 for some cards 03 for others)(8482000010...). problem is here. Can't demonstrate this.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Have a look at [gpshell](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform) that is in C or at [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) that is in Java.